# wxWidgets debug assertion failed, xtree not deferencable, when modifying wxTextCtrl value

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

When I enter a wxDialog and I focus one wxTextCtrl nothing bad happens but as soon as I modify something in that text, like deleting one character, the application crashes with this message:

"debug assertion failed: map/set iterator not dereferencable"

The last method I found out is called before crashing is this one:

```
bool wxWindowMSW::HandleKillFocus(WXHWND hwnd)
{
#if wxUSE_CARET
// Deal with caret
    if ( m_caret )
    {
        m_caret->OnKillFocus();
    }
#endif // wxUSE_CARET

#if wxUSE_TEXTCTRL
    // If it's a wxTextCtrl don't send the event as it will be done
    // after the control gets to process it.
    wxTextCtrl *ctrl = wxDynamicCastThis(wxTextCtrl);
    if ( ctrl )
    {
        return false;
    }
#endif

    // Don't send the event when in the process of being deleted.  This can
    // only cause problems if the event handler tries to access the object.
    if ( m_isBeingDeleted )
    {
        return false;
    }

    wxFocusEvent event(wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, m_windowId);
    event.SetEventObject(this);

    // wxFindWinFromHandle() may return NULL, it is ok
    event.SetWindow(wxFindWinFromHandle(hwnd));

    return GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(event);
}
```

While running the application, this method is called many times; ctrl having a value of 0x00000000 all the time and therefor not returning false in the first IF clause.
While being inside the dialog and modifying the text, the value of ctrl changes to a real value 0x031194b0; then it enters the IF clause, returns false, and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from another code modification that I still do not find how it could have this effect. Internal behaviour of wxWidgets library maybe?